# MATLAB : Reading Data from a Updating file

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code for reading from a .txt file and putting it in the code below. When used without a loop or when looped once, it works fine. But I loop infinitely or over a certain constraint,it gives the error
Error using dlmread (line 147)

Empty format character vector is not supported at the end of a file.

My .txt contains 3 values separated by spaces.
How do I debug this error?

```
 while 1
    A =dlmread("Data.txt");

   c130(30,10,0,...
    'color','red',...
    'pitch',A(1),...
    'yaw',A(2),...
    'roll',A(3),...
    'scale',2)
    view([42 8])
    axis tight
end
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a delay in the loop using `pause`? Is there another process accessing the file? How? And how are you ensuring that there’s not a race condition?

Comment: Why are you using a loop?!

Comment: The values in my .txt file keep getting updated. So I thought of using a infinite loop to keep accepting values and showing the output on basis of it

Comment: I also recommend using `pause` function as @horchler said. At the end of your code, just the line before `end`. Enter something like: `pause(0.1)` and give us a feedback.

Comment: Yes. I did add a Pause() function and it working fine. Thanks. I just want to know why is not adding pause () to the code giving an error.@horchler what do you mean by a race around condition?. Yes there was a java proram which was accessing this file to update values in it.

Comment: Without the pause this is a tight loop that may block other threads and processes from executing. Adding the pause simply gives those other items time to do their thing. A race condition may or may not be involved here. That too large of a topic to address in a comment. I suggest you Google and read about them on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).